# Set Helm Default Output Format to YAML

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

How do I set the default output of all helm to `yaml` instead of `table`?

I'm always fighting with the table format (see below).
[image]

I want this to be the default. It's much neater - but do I really have to type `-o yaml` every time?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias for your shell, something like

```
alias hl='helm list -o yaml'
```

and add it to your ~/.basrc or ~/.zshrc or whichever shell rc file you are using.

After that invoking `hl` will give you desired result

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip, but that breaks my oh-my-zsh autocomplete. And I don't want to alias all my helm commands.